# How do I say "Silly me" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

How do I say "Silly me" in Spanish?

> ¡Yo tonto! ¡Olvidé mi móvil!

Comment: In Argentina we would say: ¡Qué boludo! It is a very common Argentinian expression.

Comment: Some people have stated in their answers that you can use both _ser_ or _estar_ in the translation. There are a lot of questions regarding the difference between the two verbs all around the site, but I feel like it can be useful to write a short summary about this specific case: _¡qué tonto soy!_ implies you are always silly, while _¡qué tonto estoy!_ implies you're not usually silly, but you are in that particular moment.

Comment: In Mexico, we say: Silly me = Que tonto soy.

Comment: you could also say "soy un idiota!", but it probably sounds more harsh than saying "soy un tonto!" or "silly me!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mention *móvil*, I guess you are looking for what people would say in Spain. An option would be:

> ¡(Pero) qué tonto! Me he olvidado el móvil en el coche.

"Yo tonto" is incorrect. The shortest option would be just "tonto".

Comment: Just for completeness, in Spain you would say "coche", not "auto".

Comment: In Spain we would also prefer *me he olvidado el móvil* or even *se me ha olvidado el móvil* rather than *he olvidado mi móvil*.

Comment: "Me he olvidado el móvil" sounds completely ungrammatical in my dialect. Is this a Spain thing?

Comment: @clinch So sounds it in my Spanish as well. It wasn't me the one that chose the word. It was the OP. Then the Spaniards added the reflexive-thing.

Answer (score 8):

Some common phrases in Spain are:

- ¡Qué tonto!
- ¡Pero qué tonto!
- Qué tonto soy.

For example:

- ¡Pero qué tonto! Me dejé el móvil en casa.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other good answers:

> ¡Tonto de mí!

is the most close to the original, and correct, if slightly less colloquial than other alternative.

A colloquial idiom is

> ¡Seré tonto...!

or

> ¡... si seré tonto...!

for example (you can google for more)

> ¡Seré tonto, creí que hablabas en serio!
>
> ¡Pero si seré tonto, creí que hablabas en serio!
>
> ¡Mira si seré tonto, que creí que hablabas en serio!

Answer (score 3):

A few other expressions that can be said in this situation:

> **Estoy atontado/a**, me he dejado las llaves dentro.
>
> **Estoy agilipollado/a**, he perdido el vuelo. *(A bit coarse this one.)*
>
> ¡**Qué estupido soy**, otra vez me han timado!

Answer (score 2):

`Silly` can be translated as `tonto` or `bobo`. Also, for your example you could use both *ser* or *estar*:

> Qué **tonto** estoy, me he olvidado el móvil
>
> Mira que soy **bobo**, me he dejado el teléfono en casa.

Comment: La palabra "bobo" se dice tmb en Filipinas en exactamente el mismo contexto.

Answer (score 2):

I am adding this summary following what was discussed in [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones / Let's use community wiki to summarize set of short region specific answers](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/5481). Feel free to edit to add the term used in your country or region.

---

### Argentina

- Boludo

### España

- Tonto
- Atontado

### Filipinas

- Bobo

### México

- Tonto

Answer (score 0):

In that situation, I hear more often the form *atontado* than *tonto*. Both meaning the same, but *atontado* can only be used with *estar*.

> ¡(Es que) Estoy atontado! Me he dejado el móvil en el coche.